# Non reproducible crash on windows 10 mobile UWP app with McgInterop.McgHelpers.ThrowFailed

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Our crash reports showed us a crash in one of our application that we can't reproduce.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
0x000000005e2b83fb McgInterop.McgHelpers.ThrowFailed(Int32 hr, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHnd) in c:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Packages\appcompile-20160922-081319-21352\AC\Temp\Ilc1794386837\app-windows10.McgInterop\Helpers.g.cs at 6952:10
0x000000005e2b9855 McgInterop.ComCallHelpers.ComCall__HRESULT($__ComObject __this, RuntimeTypeHandle __typeHnd, Int32 __targetIndex) in c:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Packages\appcompile-20160922-081319-21352\AC\Temp\Ilc1794386837\app-windows10.McgInterop\SharedStubs.g.cs at 6687:5
0x000000005e2b97a7 McgInterop.ForwardComSharedStubs.Proc_<System.__Canon>(Void* InstParam, $__ComObject __this, Int32 __targetIndex) in c:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Packages\appcompile-20160922-081319-21352\AC\Temp\Ilc1794386837\app-windows10.McgInterop\SharedStubs.g.cs at 353:4
0x000000005e3d050b Microsoft.HockeyApp.Extensibility.Windows.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule.CoreApplication_UnhandledErrorDetected(Object sender, $UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs e) in  at 0:0
```

We assumed that this crash occurred at boot under some particular conditions but we were never able to reproduce it on our own device.
We also assumed that `MCG` is `Marshalling Code Generator` but we couldn't go any further.

This app is a fully `W10 Uwp App`.

Have some of you already had this kind of issue or any clue to help us?

Thanks a lot for any advice.

Comment: Have your checked the c:\windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Local\Packages\appcompile-20160922-081319-21352\AC\Temp\Ilc1794386837\app-windows10.McgInterop\SharedStubs.g.cs file?

Comment: This is an issue I have encountered in an app.  I was eventually able to reproduce it (sporadically), and narrowed it down to happening after adding several items to an ObservableCollection bound to a GridView.  Changing the ObservableCollection to a regular List fixed the issue, but you obviously lose functionality adding/removing items.  Also: I have not observed this crash on Anniversary Update or later builds of Windows.